# Where do I find the netty-tcnative-openssl-static-[os-type] jar's

Tags: java, netty

Where do I find the `netty-tcnative-openssl-static-{os_arch}` Jars for my platform? Unlike `netty-tcnative-boringssl-static-{os_arch}` they are not hosted on maven central, as described in the [netty-wiki](http://netty.io/wiki/forked-tomcat-native.html).

Comment: As mentioned in the wiki you linked, it's not available in maven central. It's actually disabled in the [build](https://github.com/netty/netty-tcnative/blob/1c0ff1909fe65f82de2ffd48bfc3e81ebee0bf59/openssl-static/pom.xml#L36). You should be able to build it yourself though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not part of the release process and so we not deploy it. That said you can build it by yourself.

Comment: That's the right answer! Unfortunately building is not that easy/possible, the most of the links in the tutorial are outdated. After some struggle I found the right links or alternative to the tools, but the build fails.

Comment: I requested an update of the tutorial at github https://github.com/netty/netty-tcnative/issues/332